# Multi Value Hot Spot Analyis in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geoprocessing, spatial-statistics, hot-spot

Is there a geoprocessing tool that will find areas that are hot or cold spots in multiple fields in the table?

I have a polygon layer with two fields. One field is the average organic soil depth for bogs and the other field is the average organic soil depth for fens. I want to know if there are any areas where both fields spatially have statistically high values compared to their respective means and vise versa.

I managed to do two separate hot spot analysis on each field and made note of the polygons that both had a hot spot, but is there a one stop tool or analysis specifically for this task?

I'm currently using a geodatabase in ArcGIS 10.3, but I'm open to using other programs and tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use *Kernel Density* tool to get "hot spot" rasters.
2. Use *Reclassify* to set values lower than your threshold to 'No Data' and to 1 above the treshold.
3. Use raster calculator with the expression ("raster_bogs" == 1) & ("raster_fens" == 1)